# Other tabs in tabcontrol not registering

Tags: vb.net, winforms

For some reason, my other 2 tabs are acting like they aren't registering in the back end code. When I open up the form I can click on all of the tabs without a problem, when I ask for the name of the selected tab it only ever gives me the name of the first tab.

So for example below, when I click on the 2nd tab and press the button that this code is a part of, the SelectedIndex in the messagebox is still 0 when it should be 1.

**EDIT:** Another note would be that, in the below code the if statement is also only registering for the "standardRates" which is the name of my first tab.

Does anyone know why it would be exhibiting this strange behaviour, or better yet how to fix it?

```
        Dim callingTab As String = ""

        MessageBox.Show(RatesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedIndex)

        If RatesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "standardRates" Then
            callingTab = "standardRates"
        ElseIf RatesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "reducedRates" Then
            callingTab = "reducedRates"
        ElseIf RatesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "disabilityRates" Then
            callingTab = "disabilityRates"
        End If
```

Comment: Is this using the standard WinForms Microsoft TabControl?

Comment: Yes sir, it's the one that's in the windows form controls in the Toolbox. Visual studio 2010

Comment: Can you reproduce in a separate project, which has nothing but the tab control in question?

Comment: Slapping a tab control on a form and popping a message box to show the selected tab works fine for me. Are you sure you're using the correct control? I notice you have `TabControl2`, can you verify that's the name in the designer of the one you are working with? Also, what is `RatesAdmin`? Is that the instance of the form or did you make a `static` field/property of a TabControl?

Comment: Yup it's the correct control, I clicked and dragged it from the All Windows Forms section of the toolbox. It's the TabControl that I'm using. Let me verify that it has the proper name in the designer.

Comment: If you cannot modify `TabControl2` from that event, then you are working with either the wrong instance of that control or the wrong instance of your form. See if you can add a new tab or something from that call.

Comment: I do notice in my designer code, there is a spot for TabPage1 but I don't see a spot for TabPage 2 or 3, maybe it didn't add them to the designer code?

Comment: If you're only seeing 1 tab in the designer then either the other tabs were not created or the custom code to create the tabs and add them to the control was not called before you pushed the button.

Comment: Yeah that's probably it, I just tried adding in 2 new tabs and they're in the designer code. I'll just copy and paste what's in my current tabs to those new ones. Hopefully that fixes the problem

Comment: If you already created the tabs in code, then you should just need to add them to the TabControl. `TabControl2.Controls.Add(myTab)`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing the problem, turns out it had nothing to do with the tabcontrol. It was operating correctly the whole time, my problem was that I wasn't passing the information correctly to my child form.

I overloaded my New() and after that everything worked the way it should:

```
Sub New(ratesAdmin As RatesAdmin)
    InitializeComponent()
    ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
    _ratesAdmin = ratesAdmin
End Sub

Private Sub AuditForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Setup connection to read database using stored procedure

        Dim callingTab As String = ""

        MessageBox.Show(_ratesAdmin.SelectedTabName)

        If _ratesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "standardRates" Then
            callingTab = "standardRates"
        ElseIf _ratesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "reducedRates" Then
            callingTab = "reducedRates"
        ElseIf _ratesAdmin.TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name = "disabilityRates" Then
            callingTab = "disabilityRates"
        End If
```

And in my parent form:

```
Dim audit As AuditForm = New AuditForm(Me)

Private Sub cmdAuditReduced_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAuditReduced.Click
    m_tabName = TabControl2.SelectedTab.Name

    audit.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Since frmRates is a new instance, you will always get the first tab.  Very unclear what you are doing here.

Comment: If I don't make it a new instance it just crashes with a null reference exception error. I think I may have figured out the problem though.

Comment: That's the problem then.  You need a reference to the existing form.  In your code snippet, you are creating a form that you aren't seeing on the screen.